# how to hide a post element when loading/adding new post to feed list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few jquery functions under document.ready and I use on() method to bubble up those functions to "load more" button and when adding a new post to the feed list.

Nevertheless, I can't hide the post footer when loading a new post. It works when first loading the page (via document.ready) but not for new posts. I already tried directly via CSS and it works and I add a new post. However, when I click on the textarea field (which would trigger the footer to show) it doesn't work.

What do you recommend? is there a way using the ON() method?

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".footer").hide();
    $(".comments-feed").hide();

    $('ol.list-feed').on('click', '.small-textarea-main-feed', function () {
        $(this).addClass("set-large");
        //$(this).("footer-post").show();
        $(this).next().find('button#cenas').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
        $(this).next('div.footer').slideDown("fast");
        $(this).next('.comments-feed').slideToggle('200');
    });

    $('ol.list-feed').on('keyup', '.set-large', function () {
        $(this).next().find('button#cenas').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
    });

    $('ol.list-feed').on('focusout', '.small-textarea-main-feed', function(){
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        } 
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("set-large");
            $(this).siblings('div.footer').hide();
            $(".comments-feed").hide();
        }
    });

    $('ol.list-feed').on('click', 'button#cancel', function () {
        $(this).parents('.footer').hide();
        $(this).parents('.footer').siblings('.small-textarea-main-feed').removeClass('set-large');
        $(this).parents('.footer').siblings('.small-textarea-main-feed').val('');
    });
});
```

HTML portion of post

When I first load the page (document.ready), it does what I want with the (.footer).hide(). However, when I add a post (have a form for that - very simple), it loads the post to the feed and it doesn't hide the post footer (code below). As I said, I alrady tried with changing the footer styling by using "display:none;" though it then affects all posts.

```
       <div id="" class="footer-condensed">
                                    <textarea class="small-textarea-main-feed" type="text" placeholder="Reply to @Gerardo"></textarea>
                                    <div id="" class="footer-post">
                                        <div id="" class="footer-submit-button" style:"display:none;">
                                            <button type="button" id="cancel" class="btn" onclick="cancel_button();" >Cancel</button>
                                                <span id="footer-btn-margin"></span>
                                            <button  type="button" id="hunch" class="btn btn-info">Hunch</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

JS for Loading posts (Yes, I tried to use the hide() method here but doesn't work - it is on comment)

```
         $('form.cenas').submit(function() {
    // 
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {

        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;

    });

    //event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        cache: false, // it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browse
        success: function(html){
                    console.log(html);
                    $("ol#list-feed").prepend(html);
                    $("ol#list-feed li:first").slideDown(600);
                    //$("ol#list-feed > li.footer").hide();
                    //$("li.comments-feed").hide();

                    document.getElementById('set-width1').value='';
                    document.getElementById('tags').value='';

                    if ($("ol#list-feed > li").size() <= 3) {
                        $('#loadmorebutton').hide();
                    } else {
                        $("ol#list-feed > li:last").remove();
                        $('#loadmorebutton').show();
                    }

                }


    });
    //event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try `.live` instead of `.on`.

Comment: @MurifoX : any specific reason you would want to use a deprecated method?

Comment: MurifoX, I would have to agree with Vandesh. I want to do it using the most updated and better way :) thanks anyway!

Comment: @ MurifoX, live is not only deprecated, it's also a hard operation. I'd propose to move this bindings into a function, with $element parameter, and each new post element, send(or map) through  this binding function

Comment: Could you post the markup (or siginificant portions) that go with your js. It isn't entirely clear what the problem you're experiencing is.

Comment: yup. A jsfiddle link would help!

Comment: But which part of your code is attempting to solve the problem? Does your cancel button work as expected? Do you add the post via javascript, or do you reload the entire page?

Comment: I post the code via .ajax(...) - javascript/jquery

Comment: Everything is working fine. I just want to hide the footer part of the post when adding a new post to the post feed list. I use on() method to bubble clicks, keyups ans so on...though I cannot figure out how to hide the footer.

Comment: In the onComplete handler of your ajax call have you tried just calling $(".footer").hide() again?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks all for your efforts. At last I figured out what was happening. Sometimes this really happens despite thinking we are aware of all things we changed...

Comment: the solution: $("ol#list-feed li div.footer-post").hide();  Instead of .footer I should be using footer-post :\ sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure whether or not I understand the structure of your page, but what I think is the following:

- You have a list of posts, each containing a footer (.footer).
- These footers are all hidden at page load ($(".footer").hide();)
- You also have a form for adding new posts, and you want the newly added post to appear with the footer hidden.

If the above is correct, you should be able to fix it by updating your succes handler like so:

```
success: function(html){
            console.log(html);

            //Create a jquery object from the returned html
            var newPost = $(html);

            //Hide the footer in the new post.
            $('.footer', newPost).hide();

            //Add the new post
            $("ol#list-feed").prepend(newPost);


            $("ol#list-feed li:first").slideDown(600);
            //$("ol#list-feed > li.footer").hide();
            //$("li.comments-feed").hide();

            document.getElementById('set-width1').value='';
            document.getElementById('tags').value='';
             if ($("ol#list-feed > li").size() <= 3) {
                $('#loadmorebutton').hide();
            } else {
                $("ol#list-feed > li:last").remove();
                $('#loadmorebutton').show();
            }
        }
```